# LibGdx returns NULL for a gl object using GL10

Tags: android

I am developing a game using LibGdx, when i tried to run the game in motorola atrix which is of 2.2.2 version, it is not accepting GL10 and giving null for gl object. Can anyone help me on this.

Code below:

```
public class Game2D implements InputProcessor, ApplicationListener {
    public void create() {
        //initializing all
    }

    public void render() {
        GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glViewport(
                0,
                0,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight()
        );
        camera.update();
        camera.apply(gl);
        //-------------------
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing a code snippet, but I feel like you're using GL related stuff before the context is initialized.

Comment: i have my Gl related code in my render() method, what i think is, in libgdx they are using OpenGl10, but in the phones they may have a support for lower version of Gl. Am i correct in this Scenario?

Comment: public class Game2D implements InputProcessor, ApplicationListener 
{
     public void create()
        {
              //initializing all
         }
     public void render()
      {
           GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();
  gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
    Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
  camera.update();
  camera.apply(gl);
                ----------
                 ---------
         }
}

Comment: the GL10 object in the code is giving null when we run in the phone, but it is running  fine in the emulator..